# Move data from columns to rows based on index and conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My sample data looks like this:

```
data = {'index':  ['001', '002', '003'],
        'A' : ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
        'B' : ['blue', 'yellow', 'green'],
        'C' : ['green', 'blue', 'red'],
        'A_new' : [2, 1, 3], 'B_new' : [0, 1, 2], 'C_new' : [0, 0, 1],
        'A_old' : [1, 0, 1], 'B_old' : [1, 0, 0], 'C_old' : [0, 0, 2],
        'A_other_new' : [2, 0, 1], 'A_other_old' : [1, 1, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['index', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A_new', 'B_new', 'C_new', 
                                'A_old', 'B_old', 'C_old', 'A_other_new', 'A_other_old']) 
df
```

output:

```
    index   A       B       C       A_new  B_new  C_new  A_old  B_old  C_old  A_other_new  A_other_old
0   001     red     blue    green   2      0      0      1      1      0      2            1
1   002     green   yellow  blue    1      1      0      0      0      0      0            1
2   003     blue    green   red     3      2      1      1      0      2      1            0
```

I am trying to move columns after column `'C'` to rows, based on index and other columns, but it has been very hard as I am just a beginner and learning Pandas. The point is to move each +1 value in columns after column `'C'` to a new row, connected via columns `'index'`, `'color'`, `'letter'` and `'reference'` to the original dataframe. Under column `'reference'`, if the original data columns `'A_other_new'` or `'A_other_old'` are > 0, I need to have a mark like `'OX'` (O is a letter, X is a number) for each +1 value. This part is important, I cannot skip it, for other steps I need to make.

Does someone have an idea on how to solve this?

### My desired output is:

```
    index   color   letter   reference  age  
00  001     red      A       A1         new     
01  001     red      A       A2         new   
02  001     red      A       A3         old
03  001     red      A       O1         new
04  001     red      A       O2         new
05  001     red      A       O3         old 
06  001     blue     B       B1         old        
07  001     green    C       C1         0 
08  002     green    A       A1         new
09  002     green    A       O1         old  
10  002     yellow   B       B1         new
11  002     blue     C       C1         0 
12  003     blue     A       A1         new
13  003     blue     A       A2         new
14  003     blue     A       A3         new
15  003     blue     A       A4         old
16  003     blue     A       O1         new
17  003     green    B       B1         new
18  003     green    B       B2         new
19  003     red      C       C1         new
20  003     red      C       C2         old
21  003     red      C       C3         old
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure i understand the `other` column in your desired output, but you can use `melt` here. If you can explain what other means it will be better:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['index', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
             var_name='other')
df['age'] = df['other'].str.split('_').str[1]
df['letter'] = df['other'].str.split('_').str[0]
print(df)

   index      A       B      C        other  value    age letter
0    001    red    blue  green        A_new      2    new      A
1    002  green  yellow   blue        A_new      1    new      A
2    003   blue   green    red        A_new      3    new      A
3    001    red    blue  green        B_new      0    new      B
4    002  green  yellow   blue        B_new      1    new      B
5    003   blue   green    red        B_new      2    new      B
6    001    red    blue  green        C_new      0    new      C
7    002  green  yellow   blue        C_new      0    new      C
8    003   blue   green    red        C_new      1    new      C
9    001    red    blue  green        A_old      1    old      A
10   002  green  yellow   blue        A_old      0    old      A
11   003   blue   green    red        A_old      1    old      A
12   001    red    blue  green        B_old      1    old      B
13   002  green  yellow   blue        B_old      0    old      B
14   003   blue   green    red        B_old      0    old      B
15   001    red    blue  green        C_old      0    old      C
16   002  green  yellow   blue        C_old      0    old      C
17   003   blue   green    red        C_old      2    old      C
18   001    red    blue  green  A_other_new      2  other      A
19   002  green  yellow   blue  A_other_new      0  other      A
20   003   blue   green    red  A_other_new      1  other      A
21   001    red    blue  green  A_other_old      1  other      A
22   002  green  yellow   blue  A_other_old      1  other      A
23   003   blue   green    red  A_other_old      0  other      A
```

Comment: thank you for your proposed answer, I need the `'age'` column to show either new or old, not something else, that's why I made the `'other'` column the way I did. I edited the original post, if you still need further information, feel free to ask :)

Comment: in the end, your proposal worked well, I added some other changes afterwards for my own dataset, but `df.melt ` is what I needed indeed - thank you :)